# how to decrease canvas pixel value by one

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'd like to change canvas pixeles value by one, but the code below returns

in firefox: [0,0,0,0] -> [78,78,78,255] -> [79,79,79,255] -> [77,77,77,255] -> [77,77,77,255]

in chromium: [0,0,0,0] -> [78,78,78,255] -> [78,78,78,255] -> [77,77,77,255] -> [78,78,78,255]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>decrease bug</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"/>
  <script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
    canvas.width = 32;
    canvas.height = 32;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

    id1 = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, 1, 1 );
    console.log( 'id1: ', id1.data );
    id1.data[0] = id1.data[1] = id1.data[2] = 78;
    id1.data[3] = 128;
    console.log( 'id1: ', id1.data );
    ctx.putImageData( id1, 0, 0 );

    id2 = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, 1, 1 );
    console.log( 'id2: ', id2.data );
    id2.data[0] = id2.data[1] = id2.data[2] = 77;
    console.log( 'id2: ', id2.data );
    ctx.putImageData( id2, 0, 0 );
    
    id3 = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, 1, 1 );
    console.log( 'id3: ', id3.data );

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Due to the lossy nature of converting to and from premultiplied alpha color values, pixels that have just been set using putImageData() might be returned to an equivalent getImageData() as different values.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData)

Comment: I'd say [Data_loss_due_to_browser_optimization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData#Data_loss_due_to_browser_optimization) is easier to read